# Grizzly Embedded Server + Jersey service + Servlet filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters, grizzly, jersey-2.0

The following code runs my REST service but my servlet filter never gets called. Any ideas?

```
WebappContext webappContext = new WebappContext("grizzly web context", "");

FilterRegistration testFilterReg = webappContext.addFilter("TestFilter", TestFilter.class);
testFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), "/*");

ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(MyResource.class);
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/myapp/"), rc);
webappContext.deploy(httpServer);
```

Comment: Can you verify the version of Jersey/Grizzly being used, please?

Comment: Jersey 2.4.1. Grizzly 2.3.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, registering your ResourceConfig in the manner as you have done above will effectively bypass the Grizzly Servlet container.

In order to leverage the Servlet Filter, you will need to something like this:

```
    WebappContext webappContext = new WebappContext("grizzly web context", "");

    FilterRegistration testFilterReg = webappContext.addFilter("TestFilter", TestFilter.class);
    testFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), "/*");

    ServletRegistration servletRegistration = webappContext.addServlet("Jersey", org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class);
    servletRegistration.addMapping("/myapp/*");
    servletRegistration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.example");


    HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
    webappContext.deploy(server);
    server.start();
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my grizzly question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123194/jersey-2-render-swagger-static-content-correctly-without-trailing-slash