# How do I register JAX-RS into an existing Grizzly HttpServer?

Tags: jax-ws, grizzly

To create a *new* instance of HttpServer with RESTful services, code looks like this:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(
    RestPingService.class
);
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
    URI.create("http://example.com:80/rest"), 
    resourceConfig, 
    false
);
```

However, this requries that I in power of creating the server. I may as well be given an *existing* instance, where other servlets/transports/whatever are already registered, and when I have to add mine.

I've been looking for a way to stick in a ResourceConfig later on, but could not find one.

In this question [Grizzly Embedded Server + Jersey service + Servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510277/grizzly-embedded-server-jersey-service-servlet-filter) one goes through a Servlet. Is that the only way? Is that slower? And how can the transport (host, port) be configured if it shall be different for the REST services?

For SOAP web services (JAX-WS) the code is straight forward; for each service instance registration goes like this

```
HttpHandler jaxwsHandler = new JaxwsHandler(soapWebService);
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(jaxwsHandler,
            //see https://java.net/projects/grizzly/lists/users/archive/2014-11/message/7 for why this is done.
            HttpHandlerRegistration.bulder()
                    .contextPath(path)
                    .urlPattern("")
                    .build());
```

And if the NetworkListener (host, port) is new then register that once:

```
httpServer.addListener(networkListener);
```

I hoped the syntax and logic would be similar. There's the JaxwsHandler, but there's no JaxrsHandler class. After all they are similar, both web services served over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ResourceConfig - you can create a Grizzly HttpHandler out of it:

```
HttpHandler httpHandler = new GrizzlyHttpContainerProvider()
                                 .createContainer(HttpHandler.class, resourceConfig);
```

and register on HttpServer as normal Grizzly HttpHandler

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer has no public constructor. And the 2 constructors take an Application, not a ResourceConfig. Is there another impl in another package?

Comment: So the question is: how to create a HttpHandler for a given ResourceConfig?